# Where to normalize submitted form values in Symfony forms?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I have a postal code field in my form, which' value should match this regex: `/^[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}$/`

In my entity I would like all postal codes to have the same format: 4 digits, a space and 2 uppercase letters, so the incoming value needs to be normalized somewhere.

Question: where do I do this conversion? I'm using Symfony's form system and Symfony version 5.4.9.

Entity:

```
class Address
{

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=7)
    * @Assert\NotBlank
    * @Assert\Regex(
    *  pattern="/^[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}$/",
    *  message="Deze waarde is geen geldige postcode."
    * )
    */
    private $postcode;

    public function setPostcode(string $postcode): self
    {
        $this->postcode = $postcode;

        return $this;
    }
    
    // other fields

}
```

FormType:

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('postcode', null, [
                'label' => 'Postcode'
            ])
            // other fields
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Address::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, the form system sets incoming valid and invalid values from the form directly onto my entity (in the `isSubmitted` method in the controller), and after that the entity is validated (in the `isValid` method).

So if I add the normalization in my entity's setter (which is called in `isSubmitted`), I would have to manually validate the incoming value before I can normalize it, but this duplicates the regex that's later executed by `isValid`. Same goes if I were to use an event listener or a transformer on the form, so neither of these seem to be a great solution.

How is this usually done?

Comment: There are [_two_ transformation steps](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#about-model-and-view-transformers). I'd do it in a `ViewTransformer` (since the input data is just an array) and just remove "basic" unwanted characters (just remove all possible formatting options, something like `return preg_replace('/[\.,\s]/', '',$data);`) and validate just a number without any formatting, then format it for display in the `transform` step. It wouldn't be formatted to be used outside forms, but that's when you can transform it again for storage.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of an extra formatting step, thank you.
I ended up using an event listener, as that added the least amount of extra code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an event listener as that required the least amount of extra code.

Restricted the regex on the entity like this:

```
class Address
{

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=7)
    * @Assert\NotBlank
    * @Assert\Regex(
    *  pattern="/^[1-9][0-9]{3} [A-Z]{2}$/",
    *  message="Deze waarde is geen geldige postcode."
    * )
    */
    private $postcode;

    public function setPostcode(string $postcode): self
    {
        $this->postcode = $postcode;

        return $this;
    }
    
    // other fields

}
```

And added an event listener for the PRE_SUBMIT event on the FormType:

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('postcode', null, [
                'label' => 'Postcode'
            ])
            // other fields
        ;

        $builder->get('postcode')->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();

            if (!\is_string($data)) {
                return;
            }

            if (preg_match('/^([1-9][0-9]{3})\s?([a-zA-Z]{2})$/', $data, $matches)) {
                $event->setData($matches[1] . ' ' . strtoupper($matches[2]));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This does change the formatting of the value that is displayed in the form in case of a submit + invalid, but I did not mind that.

If you want to keep the displayed value exactly as the user inputted it, but transform the value in the background before it is set onto the entity, you can use a ModelTransformer instead:

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('postcode', null, [
                'label' => 'Postcode'
            ])
            // other fields
        ;

        $builder->get('postcode')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($modelData) {
                    return $modelData;
                },
                function ($normData) {
                    if (!\is_string($normData)) {
                        return;
                    }
        
                    if (preg_match('/^([1-9][0-9]{3})\s?([a-zA-Z]{2})$/', $normData, $matches)) {
                        return $matches[1] . ' ' . strtoupper($matches[2]);
                    }

                    return $normData;
                }
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

Using a ViewTransformer (`->addViewTransformer`) with the same code as the ModelTransformer above also changes the formatting of the value that is displayed in the form, but with more code than the event listener.

Comment: If your concern is the amount of code to maintain, there's a neat thing that would work (at least for this specific usecase): the [`ReversedTransformer`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ReversedTransformer.php). You could use the same code as the view and model transformer by reversing it. In the view transformer, `reverseTransform` would remove formatting and `transform` would apply it and the opposite for the model, no code redundacy required. You'd end up with a normalized format in your `NormData`.

Comment: That works too, but only if I check whether `$normData` matches `/^([1-9][0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z]{2})$/` before doing the formatting. Otherwise it also "normalizes" an invalid postal code value that is re-displayed in the form after an invalid submit. And since I can't seem to get rid of the duplicate regex (listener/transformer + annotation) in anything I've tried so far, I wanted to at least keep the code as short/simple as possible.

Comment: Yes, the regex should change but, is really that big of a deal? You are not relying on user input after all, and are doing the normalization yourself. With the original regex, if it passes is already normalized. You _shouldn't_ need a regex in the transformer, a simple `substr` will do, since validation occurs _after_ normalization. Let me put an answer up summing up my comments...